# WebRTC iOS Safari: When receiving audio only stream, you can barely hear anything even when volume is maxed

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webrtc, ipados

I have an issue with iOS/iPadOS Safari 14.2 and WebRTC: When a stream is received with audio only you can't almost hear anything. But when the stream sent by peer contains video, and even when that stream is consumed by an audio tag, everything works great.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: I am also having webrtc ios issues. Likely related: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218762